# how to access c# code values into javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have code like following

```
    function AddValidation() {
            var distance=@Utilities.getConfiguration(Configuration.DistanceUOM);

            $("#km").rules('add', { chekrule: ["#PerKm", "Cost Per " +distance +"should be positive."] });

}
```

I'm getting error for `distance`  as undefined.

unable to get the proper value of `@Utilities.getConfiguration(Configuration.DistanceUOM);` in java script function

please correct me in syntax.

Comment: What does your rendered page source look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now sure what kind of project you are using.

It could be

```
function AddValidation() {
            var distance="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DistanceUOM"] %>";
            $("#km").rules('add', { chekrule: ["#PerKm", "Cost Per " +distance +"should be positive."] });

}
```

OR

```
function AddValidation() {
            var distance="@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DistanceUOM"]";
            $("#km").rules('add', { chekrule: ["#PerKm", "Cost Per " +distance +"should be positive."] });

}
```

depending on your mvc version.

Also you don't provide information what Utlilities is but if that code works in the code behind, it will also work on your view if you include the correct library at the top

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Ulities" %>
```

or

```
 @using Ulities
```

So if you include that library properly then you can use your thing:

```
function AddValidation() {
            var distance="<%= Utilities.getConfiguration(Configuration.DistanceUOM)%>";
            $("#km").rules('add', { chekrule: ["#PerKm", "Cost Per " +distance +"should be positive."] });

}
```

Can't help you more without knowledge of your project